# What is the age gap between Anakin and Padme?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, the-phantom-menace, anakin-skywalker

In Star Wars: Episode I, *The Phantom Menace*, when Anakin and Padme met for the first time, Anakin was a 5 year old child, I think. Does anyone know what was Padme's age at that time? After that, they fell in love and married. So what was the age difference between Anakin and Padme?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In 'The Phantom Menace' (set in 32 BBY) Anakin is [aged 9](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker#cite_note-Anakin_birth-2) and Padmé is [aged 14](https://starwarscardtrader.fandom.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Naberrie_-_Handmaiden_-_Base_Series_1). He turns ten during the film.

By the time of their (sexual) relationship in Attack of the Clones, set ten years later, in 22 BBY, he was 20 and she was 24. That means that the age-difference is just 4*ish* years.

> The name resonated in young Anakin’s heart and soul. He hadn’t seen
> her in a decade, not since he, along with Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon, had
> helped her in her struggle against the Trade Federation on Naboo. He
> had only been ten years old at that time, but from the moment he had
> first laid eyes on Padmé, young Anakin had known that she was the
> woman he would marry.
>
> Never mind that Padmé was several years older than he was. Never mind
> that he was just a boy when he had known her, when she had known him.
> Never mind that Jedi were not allowed to marry.
>
> <sub><sup>[Attack of the Clones: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> **Q. What's the age difference between Amidala and Anakin?**
>
> **PH:** When we meet Anakin in Episode 1, it’s just a few days before his 10™
> birthday. He’s nine years old, and Amidala is 14. Anakin turns 10 when
> he begins his Jedi training. When we catch up to them in Episode II,
> Anakin has just turned 20, and Padmé’s 24.
>
> <sub><sup>[Ask the Master - Pabli Hidalgo: Star Wars Insider #63](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_63)</sup></sub>

---

As to why she doesn't appear to age (much), I think we can put that down to an excellent moisturisation regime.

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced the difference between Hollywood's "14" and Hollywood's "24" is that big anyway . . .

Comment: I knew this because of Weird Al:  *"Did you see him hitting on the queen?  Though he's just nine and she's fourteen, yeah he's probably gonna marry her some day..."*

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: incidentally, that always seemed a bit odd to me; did he seem to be hitting on her to you?  The "are you an angel" line, badly written as it was, still struck me more as childish naivete than calculated seduction.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Maybe that's just how George Lucas thinks that 9-year olds hit on people?  Anyhow, *"Did you see him asking if the queen was an angel?"* breaks the rhyme and meter of the song, so we'll give Weird Al some leeway on that...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - He wasn't hitting on her /facepalm.

Comment: @Richard - I didn't say he was.  Weird Al did, and I quoted him.  And also suggested that maybe Lucas thought he was, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman-Maybe that's how George Lucas hits on people.

Comment: @FerusOlin A lot of people want to hit Lucas for the Sequels. And not in the nice way.

Comment: Great, now all I can think about for a few minutes is Padme, in full Naboo regalia, saying in her deadpan-monotone command voice, "Moisturize me!"

Comment: @PhasedOut. Hence the joke about needing to go to Otah Gunga to apply for the job of Padme's official moisturiser. The job isn't there, but that's **where the queue starts.**